# Struts2 JSON to Java Action Object (can't find the error)

Tags: java, json, ajax, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I have tried multiple versions and read several related answers, but I still cant figure out why Struts is not populating my Action property `user`.

This is my ajax call

```
function save_new_user() {

    var user = 
    {       username: $('#new_user_username').val(),
            email: $('#new_user_email').val(),
            password: $('#new_user_password').val()         
    };

    user_json = JSON.stringify(user);
    console.log(user_json);

    var data = {'user': user_json};

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'SaveNewUser',
        data: data,
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if(data) {

            }
        },
    });
}
```

which, by the way, print this in the console

```
{"username":"dd","email":"ff","password":"gg"}
```

My Action class (with annotations), (I am not modifying the `json-default` interceptor from struts2-json-plugin-2.3.24.1) is

```
package coproject.cpweb.actions;

import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ParentPackage;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import coproject.cpweb.utils.db.entities.UserDum;
import coproject.cpweb.utils.db.services.DbServicesImp;

@Action("SaveNewUser")
@ParentPackage("json-default")
@Results({
    @Result(name="success", type="json"),
    @Result(name="input", location="/views/error.jsp")
})
public class SaveNewUser extends ActionSupport{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /* Services  */
    DbServicesImp dbServices;

    public DbServicesImp getDbServices() {
        return dbServices;
    }

    public void setDbServices(DbServicesImp dbServices) {
        this.dbServices = dbServices;
    }

    /* Input Json  */
    private UserDum user = new UserDum();

    public UserDum getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserDum user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    /* Execute */
    public String execute() throws Exception  {

        // dbServices.saveUser(user);

        System.out.println(user.getUsername());

        return "SUCCESS";
    }


}
```

And the `UserDum` entity is

```
package coproject.cpweb.utils.db.entities;

public class UserDum {

    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

However, when the request arrives, the `json` interceptor of struts-json-plugin gets an exception trying to set "user".

```
feb 04, 2016 12:20:14 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor error
SEVERE: Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message):
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'user' on 'class coproject.cpweb.actions.SaveNewUser: Error setting expression 'user' with val
ue ['{"username":"dd","email":"ff","password":"gg"}', ]
feb 04, 2016 12:20:14 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil warn
WARNING: Missing key [invalid.fieldvalue.user] in bundles [[org/apache/struts2/struts-messages, com/opensymphony/xwork2/xwork-mess
ages]]!
```

Any clues on what might be the error?

Comment: You need to use `JSONInterceptor`.

Comment: thanks, i thought the json-default package would already include it. Should I extend the json-default package then? Do you have, by chance, an example of what I should add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending `json-default` package doesn't set `json` interceptor to the `defaultStack` of interceptors, it just defines that there is such interceptor.

Use `interceptorRefs` in your `@Action` annotation to set `json` interceptor and the `defaultStack` to the action.

```java
@Action(value="SaveNewUser", 
        interceptorRefs={ @InterceptorRef("json"), 
                          @InterceptorRef("defaultStack") })
```

Or `@InterceptorRefs` at the class level to apply interceptors to all actions defined in that class.

```java
@InterceptorRefs({
    @InterceptorRef("json"),
    @InterceptorRef("defaultStack")
})
```

Comment: I have added this as the annotations to the action
`
    @Action(value="SaveNewUser", 
    interceptorRefs={@InterceptorRef("json"),     @InterceptorRef("defaultStack")})
    @ParentPackage("json-default")
    @Results({
 @Result(name="success", type="json"),
 @Result(name="input", location="/views/error.jsp")
    })
` 
And know no error is shown, but seems the action is not executed. Nothing seems to happen in the server side after the request...

Comment: @JoseOspina Try with `@InterceptorRefs` and w/o `interceptorRefs` in `@Action`.

Comment: now my eclipse has gone mad and don't detect imports... i will delete .metadata and start over... how fun is that. I will let you know how it goes

Comment: =( , implemented with `@InterceptorRefs` and w/o `interceptorRefs` in `@Action`, but the result is the same. Action is not reached and no error is shown in the console

Comment: @JoseOspina So w/o interceptors it gives you *Unexpected Exception caught setting 'user' on...* and with interceptor action isn't called and no error? Is `input` result location being shown? Have you set devMode to true?

Comment: correct. Input is not being shown neither, and devMode is true

Comment: @JoseOspina Debug your app, find out why action isn't being called.

Comment: Wow, that was fun. I debugged Struts2 filter for the first time. It catches an Exception during the deserialization of the JSON. org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: Input string is not well formed JSON (invalid char ). I dont know why the exception does not reaches the navigator window though...

Comment: Ok, finally!. Its working. I had an error in the serialization. The X thing after "data: X", within the Ajax call must be a string of the whole object. This is '{"user":{"username":"user","email":"mail","password":"pass"}}'
Then, instead of adding the interceptor to the class, I have created, in struts.xml, a new package, with a new interceptor stack (with json and defaultStack), and set as default interceptor stack of that package.

Comment: @JoseOspina Good. Just a note: You probably should check for errors in ajax request also.

Comment: I was also stuck with the same error, and did the silly mistake while using `POSTMAN`, the body type should be set to `JSON` type, it was on `TEXT` type, which was default.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with the same error, and it was a silly mistake while using **`POSTMAN`**, the `Body type` should be set to `JSON`, for me the default option of `TEXT` type was selected.

Provided I used the JSON Interceptor.

```
<action name="sample" class="com.wildcard.action.SampleController">
            <interceptor-ref name="json"/>
             <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>

<!-- declarations for mappings from Request JSON Body goes here-->
            <result type="json">
                <param name="root">key_from_json_body</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```